# How to fix B223D error code for Jeep Grand Cherokee with engine 3.7L of year 2005

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee

Make: Jeep

Model: Grand Cherokee

Engine: 3.7

Year: 2005

Error codes: B223D

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Uncle google just told me that an airbag related sensor (most probably the one that detects if somebody is sitting on the passenger seat) needs calibration.

I only can recommend you to take the car to dealership.

Comment: *"Is it considered ok if I am just publishing a search result?"* Yeah, I mean, it's a valid answer. Happens all the time. A question with a lack of research effort may not be the best question but it doesn't preclude answers that go through the effort from being good, correct ones.